# Inserting item at particular index in clone array modifying also original array in JavaScript even if using concat

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array one is array and second one is clone array.
Structure is both of the arrays are as follows.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    links: [
        {
      id:1, 
      name:"Name1"
      },
      {
      id:2, 
      name:"Name2",
      links: [{
        name:"name2",
        url:"url2"
      }]
      },
      {
      id:3, 
      name:"Name3",
      links: [{
        name:"name3",
        url:"url3"
      }]
      }
    ],
    
  }
]

var updatedIndexAt1 = {
                id:"1.1",
        name: "UpdatedName1.1",
        links: {
        name:"name1.1",
        url:"url1.1"
        }
      };
var cloneArr = arr.concat();
var lastArr = cloneArr[0].links.splice(1, 0, updatedIndexAt1);
console.log(arr)
```

Here I am using concat method of array.concat() to copy into the clone array.
And clone array using for adding the updatedIndex1 object into the clone array using splice method.
And when I am console.log(arr) original array then that original array is modifying I do not want to modify the original array(arr).

Could someone take a look and let me know what is the issues into the following code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.concat()` only shallow clones the array. Any updates to nested items will refer to the same item as on the original. Deep clone the original array to avoid the mutation.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    links: [
        {
      id:1, 
      name:"Name1"
      },
      {
      id:2, 
      name:"Name2",
      links: [{
        name:"name2",
        url:"url2"
      }]
      },
      {
      id:3, 
      name:"Name3",
      links: [{
        name:"name3",
        url:"url3"
      }]
      }
    ],
    
  }
]

var updatedIndexAt1 = {
                id:"1.1",
        name: "UpdatedName1.1",
        links: {
        name:"name1.1",
        url:"url1.1"
        }
      };
var cloneArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)); // deep clone
var lastArr = cloneArr[0].links.splice(1, 0, updatedIndexAt1);
console.log(arr)
```